# VS Code error messages and Babel plugins

Tags: visual-studio-code, babel-plugin

How can I use this plugin

https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator

And stop VS Code from bugging me about the `|>` operator without completely turning off error checks?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

VSCode's default JSlinter should be disabled.

/.vscode/settings.json:

```
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": false
}
```

---

This is my project settings:

/.vscode/settings.json: Same above

/package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
  "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
  "eslint": "^4.19.1",
  "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
  "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
  "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1"
}
```

/.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "standard"
}
```

/.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator"]
}
```

VSCode's ESlinter works well :)